# Why does naming an interface 'Props' not give correct type-checking with a functional component? (typescript & react-native)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, tslint

- **`tslint-microsoft-contrib` version**: ^5.2.1
- **TSLint version**: ^5.11.0
- **TypeScript version**: ^3.1.6
- **Running TSLint via**: VS Code

### TypeScript code being linted

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'

interface Props {
  name: string
  color: string
  price: string
}

const Card = ({ name, color, price }: Props) => (
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: color }} />
)

export default Card
```

with `tslint.json` configuration:

```
{
  "defaultSeverity": "error",
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended",
    "tslint-config-standard",
    "tslint-react",
    "tslint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "jsRules": {},
  "rulesDirectory": ["node_modules/tslint-microsoft-contrib"],
  "rules": {
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "member-ordering": false,
    "jsx-no-lambda": false,
    "jsx-boolean-value": false,
    "interface-name": false,
    "semicolon": false,
    "react-unused-props-and-state": [
      true,
      { "props-interface-regex": "Props$", "state-interface-regex": "State$" }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Actual behavior

Typescript does not pick up on the fact that the color property has been used in the component, and reports: `[tslint] Unused React property defined in interface: color [react-unused-props-and-state]`, at the interface level.

However, if the functional component is changed to a class component, or simply, if the interface is named something other than Props e.g. CardProps - it picks up on the property's usage as expected.

### Expected behavior

I would expect the compiler to pick up on the fact that the property is being used within the component, as it does in the other scenarios mentioned above.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin right, and the compiler isn't picking up on that. It still shows color as being unused.

Comment: Apologies, I see where the confusion lies. I've updated the code example above to reflect the actual error. I changed the code to color after copying the error when I was originally using the name prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunately a known issue with tslint-microsoft-contrib. The `react-unused-props-and-state` rule does not work with stateless functional components (SFCs).  One fix is to use stateful components (classes) instead.

[image]

https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib/issues/339

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be the correct answer. I've opened up an issue on the repo and replied in that thread. Thanks Shaun.